# Would a patent on the Win32 API make Linux Wine illegal?

Tags: patents

There is the Win32 API which provides access to systems functions on Windows. For example there is the [CreateFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea) API call to create a file.

And then there is Linux Wine which implements this API to run Windows programs on Linux.

Let's say Microsoft writes a specification for the Win32 API (which in fact already exists in Form of HTML help pages) and registers a patent on it.

Would this make Linux Wine illegal?

Would this force the Linux community to remove Wine (which implements the Win32 API) from all distributions and code repositories?

I was told in this question that permission to implement a specification can be restricted by patents:

[Can the permission to implement a specification be restricted?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/86057/can-the-permission-to-implement-a-specification-be-restricted)

Comment: A different and better question would be about a hypothetical patented new feature in Windows rather than the API to access the feature.

Comment: See Google v Adobe about the Java API...

Comment: @JonCuster You mean Google vs. Oracle?

Comment: Sigh. yes... Saw too many suggested results with Adobe in it (related to both using Analytics). Dear me...

Comment: Note that Google Vs. Oracle was about copyright, not patent.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Are you sure? I think Android does not use Oracle code. They just implemented the Java spec.

Comment: @zomega - yes.  Oracle's argument was that they had copyright over the API shape itself, regardless of whether Google used any of Oracle's code otherwise.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse It's not possible to have copyright on APIs. Only patents can protect APIs (specifications). I asked this here: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/86057/can-the-permission-to-implement-a-specification-be-restricted

Comment: Strictly speaking, in America whether an API can be copyrighted is an undecided legal question - [the Google v Oracle case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_LLC_v._Oracle_America,_Inc.) was resolved by finding that Google was covered by "Fair Use", leaving the potentially more important question unanswered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Too late. It is public knowledge and has been for many years. You can't patent something that isn't new.

Comment: But there are added calls each year. These calls are brand new. Does it make a difference?

Comment: Is there an actual invention? I guess no. Software is very difficult to patent. APIs even more difficult.

Comment: Ok thanks. Maybe you can add what the max. age is to register a patent for an API.

Comment: In most of the world a patent application must be filed before the public has any knowledge of the invention. In the US there is a (sort of) one year grace period.